# PHP/Mysql based web services API for mobile app running out of mysql connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I am having issues with PHP/Mysql based web services API for one my Android Apps. Here is the problem description.

I am getting following error in error logs.

> User **my-db-user** already has more than **'max_user_connections'** active connections

My code is running out of `mysql database connections` and I have reached the maximum limit that my host can provide. I can't increase `max_connections` and `max_user_connections` anymore.

Here is how I have coded the database access in PHP scripts. I have followed this pattern everywhere, so it's same in all the database access classes and their methods like get, insert, update, delete, etc.

**DatabaseHelper.php**

```
 <?php

 class DatabaseHelper {

      private $db_host = 'my-host';
      private $db_user = 'my-db-user';
      private $db_password = 'my-password';
      private $db_name = 'my-db-name';

      public function getConnection() {
           try {
           $con = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_password, $this->db_name);
           return $con;
           } catch (Exception $ex) {
                error_log('DB Error --> ' . $ex);
                return null;
           }
      }
 }
```

?>

**Here is how I use it my database access classes.**

```
<?php

require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "pathtofile" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'DatabaseHelper.php');

class SomeDao {    

    public function get() {
        $result = array();
        $database = new DatabaseHelper();
        $mysqli = $database->getConnection();       
        if ($mysqli != null) {
            $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
            if ($stmt->prepare("SELECT columns FROM some_table")) {
                $status = $stmt->execute();
                if ($status) {
                    $stmt->bind_result($columns);
                    $records = array();
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                        // build record array
                        $record = array();
                        // add key value pairs to array
                        $record["columns"] = $columns;
                        // add $record to $records
                        array_push($records, $record);
                    }
                    $result["statusCode"] = Constants::$OK;
                    $result["statusMessage"] = "OK";
                    $result["records"] = $records;
                } else {
                    $result["statusCode"] = Constants::$SYSTEM_ERROR;
                    $result["statusMessage"] = "System Error." . $mysqli->error;
                }
                @$stmt->close();
            } else {
                $result["statusCode"] = Constants::$SYSTEM_ERROR;
                $result["statusMessage"] = "System Error." . $mysqli->error;
            }            
            @$mysqli->close();
        } else {
            $result["statusCode"] = Constants::$SYSTEM_ERROR;
            $result["statusMessage"] = "System Error.";
        }
        return $result;
    }   
}
?>
```

I believe there will be many others like me who would have faced this issue and successfully solved it. There must be some way to optimize the use of `mysql db connections` and I want to know how can I do that. I just need the optimal approach that I can use to overcome this problem.

Hope I have clearly stated my problem. Please help.

Regards

Comment: Hi @jagmohan, I hope you have resolved this issue. We are facing the same issue in one Android app and backend team is not able to resolve this. Can you please let me know how you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Opening and closing connections for each query is terribly wasteful.

It means going through the whole process of authentification and creating a different TCP connection every time you move a matchstick in and out of a table.

You will end up with a pile of dying TCP connections (with the risk of running out of TCP ports) and use a sizeable fraction of your bandwidth exchanging passwords with the DB server.

Besides, if you happen to forget to close one of these connections, it might stay alive until the end of the script, reducing the number of available connections. A kind of "connection leak", so to speak.

A typical session should look like :

```
open connection
    do some stuff
    do some stuff
    do some stuff
    do some stuff
close connection
```

and not :

```
open / do stuff / close
open / do stuff / close
open / do stuff / close
open / do stuff / close
```

Since you already have an helper class, I suggest you open the connection only once (when you instantiate the helper) and get the connection handle from it each time you need to access the database. The connection should only be closed when the helper is destroyed (i.e. at the end of the script in the worst case, or when the helper goes out of scope).

As an added benefit, it will make your code more compact. All these error reports are bulkier than the actual processing code, which makes it difficult to spot a mistake. Better take care of them in your helper object(s) so that the code can focus on getting things done.

Last but not least, you can add consistency checks in your helper object. For instance, counting the number of open connections in a static class variable, just to make sure you did not inadvertently instantiate more helpers or create more connections than you thought.

If you follow this pattern, you should have at most one DB connection per currently active request, which should max out your capacity of response.

If your pages are doing half a dozen queries through Ajax all the time, the limit will be reached that much faster. Try and reduce DB usage by factorizing your requests.

If some idiotic SEO bots or psychotic users are playing jackhammer on your site, there is little you can do except monitoring the clients IP and refuse access to those who perform too frequent queries.

Persistent connections would just allow you to mitigate the damage of doing something wrong in the first place, since "closing" them would actually not do so (and reopening them would have no impact on them either), provided you set the proper option for that.

Comment: I really appreciate your thoughts on this. What are your thoughts if I do it [this way](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/wish-list-lesson4.html)? Also, I will try it myself and load test it using Apache Jmeter.

Comment: You're welcome. The tutorial you refer to is maybe a bit too focussed on a single application, but it is nevertheless a good illustration of the way helper objects can improve reliability and readability. Maybe you could design something a bit more general purpose for your own applications?

Comment: I am thinking to re-design all the Dao classes to extend mysqli class and use static reference to connection handle. In that way, on creating a new Dao class for each new request, the code will use the static mysqli handle, there by, reducing the number of db connections. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the way to go. I'm not using MySQL that much myself, so I could not point you to existing code, but you should probably try to find some examples before designing your own tools. At the very least, have a look at the PHP/PDO interface. Even if you don't use it in the end, it is an interresting and well tought out design.

Comment: Ok, I will find some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use persistent connection.

Prefix your host with p:
Like this: instead of 
private $db_host = 'my-host';
try
private $db_host = 'p:my-host';

This only works in php version 5.3 and later.
It may or may not help you but worth a try.
Make sure to read this documentation 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

you may have to set mysqli.allow_persistent if it's not already set.

Answer (score 0):

Try using persistent connections by adding `p:` in front of `$db_host`

```
private $db_host = 'p:my-host';
```

Be sure to read [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php) though to make you don't introduce any unwanted side-effects.